# What DBus signals do I send to players to imitate Gnome's multimedia shortcuts?

Tags: ubuntu, xfce, ubuntu-11.10, dbus, multimedia

I have Xubuntu 11.10, XFCE. I want to send DBus signals to the players so that they worked like in Gnome: you press 'play' key, it plays, 'next' - it forwards, and so on.

For that, I need to bind to the multimedia keys a set of commands like this:

```
dbus-send --dest=org.gnome.Rhythmbox ...
```

Now, I searched and can't find it: what signals should I send? I need only 3 events: play, forward and rewind.

Here's what I managed to do so far:

```
culebron@vostro:~/Work/game$ dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.gnome.Rhythmbox /org/gnome/Rhythmbox org.gnome.Rhythmbox.Play
Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: Method "Play" with signature "" on interface "org.gnome.Rhythmbox" doesn't exist

culebron@vostro:~/Work/game$ dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.gnome.Rhythmbox /org/gnome/Rhythmbox org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Play
Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: Method "Play" with signature "" on interface "org.mpris.MediaPlayer2" doesn't exist
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signal sent is `org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.MediaKeys.MediaPlayerKeyPressed` on `/org/gnome/SettingsDaemon/MediaKeys`, with two arguments – the target program's name, which the program itself registers, and the key pressed ("Play", "Stop", "Next", "Previous").

```
signal sender=:1.3 -> dest=(null destination) serial=3047
 path=/org/gnome/SettingsDaemon/MediaKeys
 interface=org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.MediaKeys
 member=MediaPlayerKeyPressed
   string "gnome-mpris-keybind (mpd)"
   string "Play"
```

However, this will probably be of little use, since without g-s-d your player will fail to register itself and is not guaranteed to actually *listen for* this signal.

In some cases, you can skip this layer and control the music player directly – most players export a MPRIS2 interface at `org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.playername`, others have their custom interfaces which can be explored with D-Feet.

```
method call sender=:1.449 -> dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.mpd serial=17
  path=/org/mpris/MediaPlayer2;
  interface=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player;
  member=PlayPause
```